# Reading serial data from an input pin in Arduino

Tags: input, arduino, xbee

I have a [GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) serial signal coming from *Dout* of [XBee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee). I checked it with oscilloscope and signal exists.

How can I read serial signal with Arduino (I assume I should feed it to an input pin)?

And then print it to *Serial Monitor*.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to read the GPS signal sent to the RX pin.

It is in the Arduino IDE under menu *File* → *Examples* → *Communications* → *SerialEvent*

```
String inputString = "";         // A string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // Whether the string is complete

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Reserve 200 bytes for the inputString:
  inputString.reserve(200);
}

void loop() {
  // Print the string when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {
    Serial.println(inputString);

    // Clear the string:
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }
}

/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the
  hardware serial RX.  This routine is run between each
  time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can delay
  response.  Multiple bytes of data may be available.
 */
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // Get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();

    // Add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;

    // If the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now connect the wire that has serial signal to the RX (pin 0) and run *Serial Monitor* and you will see something like this:

```
$GPGLL,5652.36437,N,08901.52702,W,225356.00,A,D*73
$GPGSV,4,1,15,07,42,306,33,08,16,110,33,09,53,253,37,10,05,281,23*72
$GPRMC,225357.00,A,5652.36445,N,08901.52698,W,0.145,,180315,,,D*62
```

Comment: Note serialEvent() is ***line-oriented*** (not very clear in the documentation, absent in the code comments, and misleading in the example code). That is, a newline (whatever that is. ASCII 13?) is required before serialEvent is called. The canonical is *[Arduino "SerialEvent" example code doesn't work on my Arduino Nano. I can't receive serial data. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013619/)*